# How can I reference Sheet1 name in a different Sheet in the same workbook in excel 2010?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to capture the "Sheet1" name in a cell in Sheet2. This formula gives me the Sheet2 (current sheet) name. How can I modify it to give me sheet 1 name?

=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the sheet name in front of the `A1`:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",Sheet1!A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet1!A1))+1,255)
```

Excel is smart enough that if the sheet name changes it will change the reference.